# Why does Bootstrap's text-decoration:none not work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

**QUESTION:**

Why does Bootstrap not remove hyperlink underlines with its `text-decoration: none`?

**BREAKDOWN:**

By default, Bootstrap gives all hyperlinks `text-decoration: none` with the low-specificity CSS:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

However, this doesn't actually remove the default underline from hyperlinks:

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#">Should have no text-decoration</a> (through Bootstrap)
</body>
```

There are no rules with higher specificity than `text-decoration: none`. In fact, there are no other rules affecting text-decoration at **all**. When Bootstrap is removed, and the same CSS is added in its place, the text-decoration **is** removed:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Should have no text-decoration</a> (inline)
```

Bootstrap also seems to take 'priority' with this behaviour; when you use the above CSS in conjunction with Bootstrap, it doesn't matter whether your declaration has more specificity or not; links will still be underlined:

```css
a, div a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#">Bootstrap has higher specificity</a>
  <div>
    <a href="#">Inline CSS has higher specificity</a>
  </div>
</body>
```

It's interesting to note that adding `!important` removes the decoration, even though there are no 'more specific' declarations:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#">!important</a>
</body>
```

So why does Bootstrap not remove the default hyperlink underline with its implementation of `text-decoration: none`?

Comment: Don't see any underline in current Chrome.

Comment: Seems to only be underlined while in a :hover state.

Comment: As it turns out, the hover in Bootstrap actually *is* applying a higher specificity; `text-decoration: underline`; comes from `a:focus, a:hover` in `tab-focus.less`, which obviously has higher specificity than just `a`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you're referring to the underline when you hover over the link, since that is the only thing that seems to not be working.

The answer is simple: you are not targeting the hover state. It's also usually recommended to treat the focus state as well, for keyboard navigation. Try this...

```
a, a:hover, a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Correct; I didn't initially realise that Bootstrap is automatically applying `text-decoration: underline` in `a:focus, a:hover` (in `tab-focus.less`). I should have spotted this. Declaring the hover state in the declaration does indeed fix the problem -- this is the correct answer, and I will mark as accepted in a few minutes when the system lets me :)

Comment: To further clarify, the more correct way to override default Bootstrap styles is to include your own variables.scss (or variables.less) BEFORE Bootstrap's styles, and then compile that to CSS as part of your build process. In this case, you would set the `$link-hover-decoration` variable to none, instead of underline, seen in this section of variables http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#scaffolding.

Answer (score 0):

Despite what you said, there's a CSS rule in your project that's overriding Bootstrap's `text-decoration: none`. The links in your demo code behaves properly.

### It might be your browser settings

If loading your page on a different browser fixes things, this is the case. Some browsers allow users to override specific CSS styles.

### It might be another CSS file

Load the page on Google Chrome. Right-click on the link, then click on "Inspect Element". You'll see all CSS rules in effect, including one that prevents Bootstraps `text-decoration: none` from working.